# 'this' undefined in chrome, but works in IE

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, csom

below, the function works in IE, which is Good, but I need it to work in Chrome, FireFox, etc as well...
In Chrome Im getting an Error... Heres my code

```
function loadList(list_name) {
    var oList = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(list_name);
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>');
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
```

... it says in Chrome..  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'collListItem' of undefined..

I am assuming this is from the "this" .. is there a difference on how chrome handles 'this' and ie handles 'this'??

What can I do about this ? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is involuntarily (or deliberately?) under strict mode due to some sloppy concatenation or such, this means function calls without explicit receiver place `undefined` as `this` value  instead of the global object. Older IEs don't recognize the strict mode so it keeps working like it has before.

Just change `this` to `window`.

Fun fact: this has happened to [amazon too](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=579119)